# How to create an octal reppresentation out of a sequence of boolean atoms in erlang

Tags: erlang

I must confess that the erlang binary syntax has confused me.

I want to issue the file:change_mod/2 function but to prepare the integer value that contains the file mode ( 755, 740, etc ) I want to construct it from a list of boolean atoms such as:

```
[ true, true, true, true, false, true, true, false, true ]
```

which would be equivalent to 111 101 101 = 755 in octal (base8)

I am unable to find a direct way to do this with bit string representation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I came up with so far:

```
1> Inp = [true, true, true, true, false, true, true, false, true].
[true,true,true,true,false,true,true,false,true]
2> Lst = [if X =:= true -> 1; X =:= false -> 0 end || X <- Inp].
[1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1]
3> B = lists:foldl(fun(A, AccIn) -> <<AccIn/bits,A:1>> end, <<>>, Lst).
<<246,1:1>>
4> Int = binary:decode_unsigned(<<0:((8-(bit_size(B) rem 8)) rem 8), B/bits>>).
493
5> io:fwrite("~.8B~n", [Int]).
755
ok
6>
```

The [function `binary:decode_unsigned`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/binary.html#decode_unsigned-1) expects the input value to be a multiple of one byte, therefore we may have to pad it.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative way:

```
-module(bits).

-export([bit_flag/1]).

bit_flag(Flags) ->
    Bits = length(Flags),
    <<X:Bits/integer>> = << <<(to_bit(Flag)):1/integer>> || Flag <- Flags >>,
    X.

to_bit(true) -> 1;
to_bit(false) -> 0.
```

Answer (score 2):

One way could be like this:

```
List = [ true, true, true, true, false, true, true, false, true ],

{_, Mode} = lists:foldr(
    fun(A, {M, S}) -> {M * 2, (A * M) + S } end,
    {1, 0},
    [case X of true -> 1; false -> 0 end || X <- List]
).

Mode =:= 8#755.
true

io:format("~.8B~n", [Mode]).
755
ok
```

Or as a module:

```
-module(change_mode_utils).

-export([bool_list_to_mode/1]).

-spec bool_list_to_mode(List::[boolean()]) -> integer().
bool_list_to_mode(List) when is_list(List) ->
    {_, Mode} = lists:foldr(
        fun(true,  {M, S}) -> { M * 2, M + S };
           (false, {M, S}) -> { M * 2,     S } end,
        {1, 0},
        List
    ),
    Mode.
```

Proof

```
1> c(change_mode_utils).
{ok,change_mode_utils}
2> change_mode_utils:bool_list_to_mode(
    [ true, true, true, true, false, true, true, false, true ]
) =:= 8#755.
true
```

Comment: thanks but i do understand the way that change_mode and chmod works. My question is specific on how to get a sequence of booleans and convert it to a octal form without going through power of two's numeric sums.

Comment: Corrected to answer your question.

Comment: great approach thanks. I like Yasir's take as well using /bits